# Looping through multiple string variables and cases to create a numeric variable SPSS

Tags: loops, vector, syntax, spss

I have a dataset in SPSS with 311 different variables and 1304 cases. 99 of those variables have ICD9 and ICD 10 codes which are sometimes only numeric (i.e. 303) and sometimes string (i.e. H233). I have made all of the variables string.

What I need to do is have SPSS go through each case and each of the 99 variables and see if it finds any of the codes from a large list of the codes, i.e.:

```
("3180","3181","3182","330","33111","33119",
"3314","33189","3319","3320","3321","3330",
"3332","3334","3335","3337","3339","334",
"335","343","34501","34581","3590","3591",
"3592","3593","3361","3368","3379","3418",
"34290","343","3440","34481","3449","34511",
"3453","34541","34561","34571","34591","3481",
"3484","3491","43401","43491","359","740",
"741","742","7595","78003","9962","99663",
"V452","V5301","V5302")
```

If it finds any for my specified list of variables I need it to make the variable `ccc_n = 1`, otherwise `ccc_n` needs to equal 0. I tried `COMPUTE ccc_n = 0`. How can I accomplish this? I have tried `do repeat`, `do if`, `loop` and `vector` but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
do repeat vr=vr1 to vr99.
  compute ccc_n=any(vr, "3180","3181","3182","330","33111","33119" ....).
end repeat.
```

You should of course replace `vr1 to vr99` with your real variable names (if they are not consecutive in the file you need to name them each separately). In the `any()` function enter all of your codes separated by commas.